# How can you make a drawing with ther letters?

Tags: drawing, letter, ascii-art

[image]

Is there any way of drawing something like this automatically?
If yes please tell me, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This site is not about how to make your computer do things, conceptually. To have an on-topic question, you would have to choose an implementation language, and at least have the intent of writing code to solve the problem. Ideally you would have made some attempt already, or at least shown your thought process about the logical steps needed to solve the problem, along with a clear question about what part you need help with.

Comment: If you want an existing program that can do this for you, that's explicitly off topic here. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel did not know about the stackexchange site that you mentioned. Would you recommend me removing my answer? I would not like a flooding of downvotes for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fas as I know, there are plenty of online ascii art generators. Here's one that I've used a few times:

https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20

You would copy it from the browser and paste it in the comment in the code.